# Error in the page on Privileges (in the tag synonyms section)

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, privileges-page

In [Suggest and vote on tag synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms), the paragraph captioned "How do I propose or vote on tag synonyms?" has this: *Any suggested synonyms for the tag will appear below that which up and down arrows so that eligible users ...* It should be **with** and not **which**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been fixed in the Meta privileges wiki. The change will get pushed out to all sites whenever the devs push changes next.